# Connect R to MySQL database with Standard TCP/IP over SSH Connection

Tags: r

So the title says a lot about my current issue. I am currently connected to a MySQL database at my internship through a Standard TCP/IP over SSH connection. I am trying to connect R to this database using the RMySQL and dbConnect packages (unless there is a better way of course). My connection code (with password and dbname taken out) is:

```
con = dbConnect(MySQL(), user="readonly", password="password",
      dbname="dbname", host="localhost")
```

and I received the following error message,

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) :
Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user
'readonly'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I was able to connect to my local MySQL database using this function, but am having trouble connecting to the company database with the SSH connection. If anybody has any insight on this issue (whether I'm missing any parameters in the function, an alternative way to connect, etc.), that would be great!

Best,
Nicholas